# How to make textbox as not editable in asp.net(c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I've creating one ASP web application, in that application one form have to update date value in the textbox field i put calender button near that textbox. it can update the date in that textbox field but its editable . i want update date value through only using calender button , i used read-only property but return empty value so not works .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try client side html `readonly` attribute instead of ASP.NET server side `readonly`.

```
myTextBox.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
```

From MSDN,

> The Text value of a TextBox control with the ReadOnly property set to true is sent to the server when a postback occurs, but the server does no processing for a read-only text box. This prevents a malicious user from changing a Text value that is read-only. The value of the Text property is preserved in the view state between postbacks unless modified by server-side code.

This is why textbox with server side `readonly` attribute has null value in postback.

Answer (score 5):

You can use either 
`TextBox1.Enabled = false;` OR

`TextBox1.Attributes.Add("readonly","readonly");`

Difference is that if you make `enabled= false` then you cant pass the value of the `textbox`.  If you need to pass the value of the `textbox` then you should use read-only property of `textbox`.

Answer (score 1):

On page load event of your code behind file just write following code:

```
yourTextBoxName.Attributes.Add("readonly","readonly");
```

you can also do same by using property

```
Enabled="false"
```

on your aspx page but then you will not be able access its value in code behind page.

Comment: "yourTextBoxName.Attributes.Add("readonly","readonly");" is better becaue it allows your textbox to be resizable and "Enabled="false"" not.

Answer (score 1):

You can make textBox non-editable in asp.net

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox1" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use this:

```
TextBox1.Enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

By using read only it will give problems on post back just set this java script property

```
onkeydown="javascript:return false"
```

by using this u can have properties like readonly and have absolutely no problem will araise